# Help Installing ee 3.0.0 (beta)

Tags: ee

I've looked around in the documentation and on the forums for help with this, but to no avail. I'm having trouble figuring out how to install the new public beta for ee. The current install information for v2x does not seem to coincide with the new file structure for 3.0.0.

I have uploaded ee to my server but cannot figure out which files I should change permissions for?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really quite simple...

First, create a new folder in your web root (or use your webroot) and extract the contents of the `ExpressionEngine3.0.0-beta.zip` file there. Ex:

```
/your_web_root/ee3/
```

Then, simply visit

```
http://www.your-domain.com/ee3/admin.php
```

To begin the installation process. It looks different, but it's exactly the same. It will warn you if:

1. Your `config.php` file isn't writable (666).
2. Your `cache` folder isn't writable (777).
3. Your `database.php` file isn't configured (haven't added DB creds to it).
4. Basically, nothing else, unless your server doesn't pass basic tests for compatibility.

Really, it's almost the exact same [installation as EE2.x](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/installation.html).

Comment: I"ve looked around for all files named "config.php" and "database.php" and changed the permissions to either 666 or 777 depending on the file. When I go to the front page of the installation, I get the error: **"Your config file does not appear to be formatted correctly."**

Comment: You are not visiting the address I asked you to. **admin.php** is the file you need to hit, **not** index.php. So `/ee3/admin.php`, not `/ee3/index.php` or just `/ee3/`.

Comment: To reiterate, you must add `admin.php` to the end of your front page URL.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I figured it out. I needed to go to admin.php in my browser, rather than the front page.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct, as I directed you to do so. Thank you.